# Error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)",where is the error?

Tags: c

An excercise asks to make a function for managing a theater: I want a chained list, where each element is a row(of the audience) with its number of free seats (in that row) and the sublist of seats in each. This is my function for making the list,where is the error?

```
struct posto {
  int stato;
  struct posto *next;
};

typedef struct posto Posto;
typedef struct posto *PuntatorePosto;

struct fila {
  int numero;
  PuntatorePosto Lista;
  struct fila *next;
};

typedef struct fila Fila;
typedef struct fila *PuntatoreFila;

typedef enum {
  false,
  true
} Boolean;

struct fila *crealista() {
  struct fila *p, *ultimo, *ultimino;
  struct posto *p1, *p2;
  int i, j, n, m;

  do {
    printf("\t\t\tCreazione della lista\n\nDa quante file %c composta la "
           "platea ? ",
           138);
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Quanti posti per fila ? ", 138);
    scanf("%d", &n);
  } while (n < 0);

  if (n == 0)
    p = NULL; /* lista vuota */
  else {

    p = (struct fila *)malloc(sizeof(struct fila));
    ultimo = p;
    ultimo->numero = 1;

    for (i = 2; i <= m; i++) {
      ultimo->next = (struct fila *)malloc(sizeof(struct fila));
      ultimo = ultimo->next;
      ultimo->numero = i;
    }
    ultimo->next = NULL;

    ultimino = p;
    p2 = ultimino->Lista->next;
    for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {

      printf("Fila %d posto 1", i);
      scanf("%d", &p2->stato);
      for (j = 2; j <= n; j++) {
        p2->next = (struct posto *)malloc(sizeof(struct posto));
        p2 = p2->next;
        printf("Fila %d posto %d", i, j);
        scanf("%d", &p2->stato);
      }
      ultimino = ultimino->next;
      p2 = ultimo->Lista->next;
    }
    ultimino->next = NULL;
  }
  return (p);
}
```

Comment: Where does the segfault happen?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code?

Comment: You are never setting `ultimo->Lista`

Comment: Please note that using non-english variable names makes it considerable harder for people to answer you. You may get better and/or faster results if you use english. Refer to the meta-discussion [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/266581#266581).

Answer (score 2):

The good idea is to run the program in debugger or memory access validator.

One option is gdb that can be started with command gdb ./yourprogaram. Next you have to start running it with command run. Later on you can view backtrace of crash and read the variables in the program memory.

Another option is valgrind that does memory access checking and prints useful information about errors.

Mastering debugging tools is a very important skill for programmers. That why it is best to try them on simple programs from start.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `Lista` which is likely the cause for your segfault. Add some headers (`#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`) and recompile it with debugging symbols and warnings on (and a `main` function):

```
cc -Wall -Wextra -g yourfile.c -o yourfile
```

Then use `gdb` to debug this:

```
gdb -q -ex r ./yourfile
```